# How to write dual Lagrange equation in Python using sympy?

Tags: python, optimization, sympy, svm, equation

[image]

```
from sympy import symbols
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.466,0,0,0,0,-0.466,0,0,0,0,0.466,0,0,0,0,0.590], [0.377,0,0,0,0,-0.377,0,0,0,0,0.377,0,0,0,0,0.755], [0.18,0,0,0,0,-0.18,0,0,0,0,0.18,0,0,0,0,0.949]])
y = np.array([-1, -1, 1])

def lagrange_dual(x, t):
    result = 0
    alpha = symbols('alpha')
    
    for i in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            result = result + alpha[i]*alpha[k]*t[i]*t[k]*np.dot(x[i, :], x[k, :]) 
    result = 0.5*result - sum(alpha)
         
    return result
print(lagrange_dual(x, y))
```

I'm trying to write the Lagrange form of svm in python but I get this error how can I solve it?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-372723adcf7d> in <module>
     32 
     33     return result
---> 34 print(lagrange_dual(dat, labels))
     35 
     36 

<ipython-input-59-372723adcf7d> in lagrange_dual(x, t)
     28     for i in range(3):
     29         for k in range(3):
---> 30             result = result + alpha[i]*alpha[k]*t[i]*t[k]*np.dot(x[i, :], x[k, :])
     31     result = 0.5*result - sum(alpha)
     32 

TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable
```

the main goal is to achieve out put of this function for n data

Comment: You defined alpha to be a symbol. A symbol is not an iterable (it is not a list, tuple, array)... But then you attempt to access its elements, like it is an array (or list, tuple, ...). Without further details it's difficult to suggest an appropriate solution. What are you trying to compute? Specifically, what's the next operation you'd like to apply to the output of lagrande_dual?

Comment: consider editing your title to make it more specific to your problem. I would probably add `sympy` to the title.

Maybe, "`How to write dual Lagrange equation in Python using sympy?`"

Comment: @JacobBumgarner see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). The title should be descriptive, indeed, but should also avoid duplicating the tags of the post.

Comment: hi ! actually I need those sentences for calculating some weights for dual formation of svm  @Davide_sd

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this should give you what you were looking for.

Here is the expression:

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0.466,0,0,0,0,-0.466,0,0,0,0,0.466,0,0,0,0,0.590], [0.377,0,0,0,0,-0.377,0,0,0,0,0.377,0,0,0,0,0.755], [0.18,0,0,0,0,-0.18,0,0,0,0,0.18,0,0,0,0,0.949]])
t = np.array([-1, -1, 1])  # not sure what this was for?
y = _ ### define y
a = _ ### define alpha
m = _ ### define m

# define the sympy symbols
m_sym = sp.Symbol("m")
i, j = sp.symbols("i  j",  cls=sp.Idx)
a_sym = sp.IndexedBase("a")
x_sym = sp.MatrixSymbol("x", x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
y_sym = sp.IndexedBase("y")

# define the expression
expr = sp.Sum(a_sym[i], (i, 0, m_sym)) - 0.5 * sp.Sum(
    sp.Sum(
        a_sym[i] * a_sym[j] * y_sym[i] * y_sym[j] * 
        sp.DotProduct(x_sym[i, :], x_sym[j, :]),
        (i, 1, m_sym),
    ),
    (j, 1, m_sym),
)
```

Then if we print the expression, we get:

```py
>>> sp.pprint(expr)
  m                m     m                                                  
 ___              ___   ___                                                 
 ╲                ╲     ╲                                                   
  ╲                ╲     ╲                                                  
  ╱   a[i] - 0.5⋅  ╱     ╱   a[i]⋅a[j]⋅y[i]⋅y[j]⋅x[i:i + 1, :]⋅x[j:j + 1, :]
 ╱                ╱     ╱                                                   
 ‾‾‾              ‾‾‾   ‾‾‾                                                 
i = 1            j = 1 i = 1
```

You can then turn this expression into a function and evaluate it using `sp.lambdify`. I don't have your variables for evaluation, so I'm just going to fill it with the dummy variables that I created above.

```py
func = sp.lambdify((a_sym, x_sym, y_sym, m), expr)
func(a, x, y, m)  # will produce your answer
```

Comment: thanks so much ! but at the end I got this error                                                                TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e3f210d717f7> in <module>
     34 
     35 func = sp.lambdify((a_sym, x_sym, y_sym, m), expr)
---> 36 func( a,x, y,3)

TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given                                                           @Jacob Bumgarner

Comment: I just reran all of that code in a clean jupyter notebook and had no errors. How did you define your `a`, `x`, and `y` variables?

Comment: I run the same code on colab but with the same error unfortunately 'a' is symbol and 'x' is defined above  x = np.array([[0.466,0,0,0,0,-0.466,0,0,0,0,0.466,0,0,0,0,0.590], [0.377,0,0,0,0,-0.377,0,0,0,0,0.377,0,0,0,0,0.755], [0.18,0,0,0,0,-0.18,0,0,0,0,0.18,0,0,0,0,0.949]])     and 'y' is t = np.array([-1, -1, 1])      @ 
Jacob Bumgarner

Comment: `a` must have some value that will be used when solving the equation. If you don't want to define `a` and `m` in order to evaluate the equation, then what exactly did you want...? You can't just call the function without having defined the variables that you're inserting.

Answer (score 0):

To put it shortly, the error means one of the items you're trying to call isn't an array. Try adding each item in the equation seperately, so you can see what the issue is. Ex: `AlphaI = alpha[i]`, etc.
Only add/multiply at the end.

Hope this helps!